# Tracking my Wii Sports Tennis scores

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-sports

What's the least obtrusive and most efficient way to track my Wii 
Tennis scores? I realize I could write down the info I wanted after 
each game, but that takes time and breaks the rhythm.

I know the Wii stores these internally, but the format's encrypted, so 
there's no way to export the data anywhere(?), not even using the SD 
card.

The stats I'd ideally like to keep:

- Time game ended
- Whether I won or lost
- My Wii Tennis ranking after game (eg, 1000 = pro)
- Which computer opponents I played
- Which Mii I used to play this game (I use several)
- The loser's score (ideal: scoring history for game)
- Length of game
- Anything else interesting

but any subset is fine.

I realize Wii Mail has some of this info, but I don't think that can 
be exported either?

Using my cell phone to take a screenshot is one solution, but I don't 
get all the info I want AND it does break my rhythm slightly.

EDIT: Re reading data directly off the SD card, I've now copied the "data.bin" file from the Wii Sports directory to http://oneoff.barrycarter.info/wiisports.bin

I also downloaded http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Segher's_Wii.git and ran "tachtig", and the results are at http://oneoff.barrycarter.info/RPSports.dat

Note that Segher's Wii does **some** decryption, but RPSports.dat is still not plaintext or anything similar. There appear to be multiple levels of encryption at work here.

Comment: The only bad part of Wii Sports is its refusal to give detailed stats on its games. I wonder if you copied the saved game file to your SD card if you could extract the data then.

Comment: @Jack B Nimble, I've actually done that and have the data.bin files on my computer. I even downloaded and ran tachtig from http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Segher's_Wii.git, but the saved data remains encrypted in some weird form that I don't understand ("strings data.bin" is of no help at all... the data really is encrypted, not just encoded, I think)

Answer (score 3):

This is difficult, but it's not impossible. You've passed the first hurdle by recovering the RPSports.dat file, the next step is popping the file into a hex editor and looking for offsets.

Start with a blank save file and save the minimum amount of detail - record every bit of that detail in a log. Open that file in a hex editor and look for something that makes sense- I would search for the date code stored in bitfield format. From there, you can begin searching for offsets and values stored in 2 bit hex strings.

This is a great intro to the parsing subject: jansenprice.com/blog?id=9-Extracting-Data-from-Wii-Fit-Plus-Savegame-Files

I was able to use many of these details, and a lot of tinkering to create an online parser for wii fit weight. I started with a parser that I found, and just converted everything to plaintext hex with binascii.b2a_hex (python) so i could figure out the correct values and worked backwards until it worked. You can see my working parser at http://www.getmyfitdata.com - it pulls weight, date, balance, and bmi from the wii fit save file.

Can you post some details about the RPSports.dat file so we can begin looking for values/offsets? Specifically, what date was it created, what was the score, what was the Mii name, etc.

It looks like game data starts at offset 0x2CC with 455 bytes for each game store.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is a single answer but:

Here is a [forum](http://forums.nintendo-scene.com/index.php?topic=797.0) (and code) that talks about the encryption on wii saved games. http://forums.nintendo-scene.com/index.php?topic=797.0

You might also consider the sources of [Homebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_homebrew). If they can jailbreak a wii to run non-authorized programs I would guess those programs can decrypt the saved games using the wii's internal cert.